# How to find empty space in a rectangle which has 2 circles in it?

Tags: c, area

I'm solving a problem in **Toph** . In this problem I've to find out the empty space of a rectangle which has 2 equal circles in it.

[here is the problem](https://toph.co/p/circles-in-a-rectangle)

```
#include <stdio.h>
float pi=3.1416;
int main()
{
    int i,t;
    float r,rest;
    scanf("%d",&t);
    for(i=1;i<=t;i++)
    {
        scanf("%f",&r);
        rest=(4*r*2*r)-(2*pi*r*r);
        printf("Case %d: %.2f\n",i,rest);
    }
    return 0;
```

Here is my solve. It returns a correct value for first test case but it fails to solve the second one.
What's the problem???

Comment: Maybe change `float` into `double`

Comment: Simplify the formula?

Comment: Simplify the formula has a problem. It returns a incorrect value for the first case.

Comment: IMO the sample output is wrong.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show your exact input as well as the expected and the actual output. Also use `double` instead of `float` and `scanf("%f",&r);` instead of `scanf("%f",&r);`

Comment: I am not able to reproduce the behavior. getting the expected o/p. [here](https://onlinegdb.com/HyIkZ3gx8)

Comment: In this website you can only see the first input and output

Comment: @Jabberwocky: what is the difference of two `scanf` you have mentioned? I see no difference

Comment: @TruthSeeker sorry, a typo: the first should be `scanf("%lf",&r)`

Comment: `float pi=3.1416;`  Only to [politicians](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indiana_Pi_Bill).

Comment: @adib I think simple formula should be Empty Space = Area of Rectangle - 2*(Area of Circle). as 2 circles are equal. With of course added validation for area of circle not exceeding area of rectangle ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>`float pi=3.1416;` is the cause of the problem. Under the math header file (`#include <math.h>`) there is a constant `M_PI` use it instead.</strike>

Edit:
Sorry, didn't read thoroughly, apparently the problem is in the floating point precision. If you change all float values into double it should work.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
double pi=3.1416;
int main()
{
    int i,t;
    double r,rest;
    scanf("%d",&t);
    for(i=1;i<=t;i++)
    {
        scanf("%lf",&r);
        rest=(4*r*2*r)-(2*pi*r*r);
        printf("Case %d: %.2lf\n",i,rest);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: But in the question the value of pie has given

Answer (score 0):

Unlike 2 and 8, the reason `double` is more accurate is because `float` cannot represent [3.1416](https://www.binaryconvert.com/result_float.html?decimal=051046049052049054) as well as the input values:

```
3.1416 -> 3.1415998935699462890625
40.082 -> 40.082000732421875
85.8   -> 85.8000030517578125
```

There's simply not enough precision, (note that [IEEE-754 `float`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format#IEEE_754_single-precision_binary_floating-point_format:_binary32), which is overwhelmingly used for `float`, stores it in base-2.) Most probably, the later numbers were probably specifically generated in order to fail the test cases. If one wants to know more, [Don’t Store That in a Float](https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2012/02/13/dont-store-that-in-a-float/), and [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

The numerical constant is `1.7168`, which is exact assuming their version of *pi*, (times `r*r`.) The best one could with single-point precision is `1.7167999744415283203125`, which is off by `2.55584716796875E-8`. With a `double`, it's `1.71680000000000010373923942097`, off by `1.0373923942097E-16`, plus the values input.